# Singleton design discussion: Why shouldn't all of a singleton's variables and functions be static?

Tags: swift, singleton

I'm asking this question for discussion about object oriented singletons.

I've been creating a few Singleton classes for a framework lately in Swift, and learned that static variables in Swift are [lazily instantiated](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=7) just as it is in Java. After looking up swift singleton designs, I've never yet seen a singleton like below.

If this is true, and static variables aren't on the global stack, why not create a singleton like so? Where both variables and functions are static:

```
class Singleton {

    private static let  = Singleton()

    private static var someString: String = "blah"

    private init() {    }

    public static someFunction() -> String {
        return Singleton.someString
    }

}
```

Comment: That a particular class is singleton doesn't mean that it has no superclasses or superinterfaces. Static fields and methods are not polymorphic.

Comment: But also, there is exactly one instance of a singleton class. If all of its fields and methods are static, you don't need *any* instances of the class. As such, it'd not be a singleton, it'd be a "zero-ton".

Comment: Is there a name for this design pattern? I've found a few times where it's useful for a Configuration class to hold and set specific variables, or when wrapping database accessors. I don't feel right holding large objects Statically so I don't believe there's any design patterns that solve this, but that might just be me being prude